# Исключения при попытке сдвинуть указатель C++

Tags: c++, выделение-памяти

Я пишу класс для выделения памяти и сохранением количества байтов который занимает блок памяти. Работает так: Выделяем память размером n + 8/4 (x64, x32), где n - нужное количество байт. В эти 8 байтов пишем сколько байтов занимает блок памяти. Сдвигаем на 8 байтов, используем.

Возникает исключение на 44 строчке кода:

> 0x6F6C6C6540, "Нарушение доступа для чтения"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <malloc.h>

using namespace std;

#ifdef _WIN64
    #define SIZEBLOCK_BYTES 8
#else
    #define SIZEBLOCK_BYTES 4
#endif

template<class T>
T* move_pointer_right(void* ptr, size_t bytes)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<bool*>(ptr) + bytes);
}

template<class T>
T* move_pointer_left(void* ptr, size_t bytes)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<bool*>(ptr) - bytes);
}

class BSmartheap
{
private:
    vector<void*>infoheap;
public:
    void* allocate_block(size_t sizeBytes);
    void free_memory(void* blockMem);
    size_t size_block(void* blockMem);
};

size_t BSmartheap::size_block(void* blockMem)
{
    const size_t sizevec = infoheap.size();
    for (size_t x = 0; x < sizevec; x++)
    {
        if (&infoheap[x] == blockMem)
        {
            return move_pointer_left<size_t>(infoheap[x], SIZEBLOCK_BYTES)[0]; // exception here
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void BSmartheap::free_memory(void* blockMem)
{
    const size_t sizevec = infoheap.size();
    for (size_t x = 0; x < sizevec; x++)
    {
        if (&infoheap[x] == blockMem)
        {
            free(move_pointer_left<void>(infoheap[x], SIZEBLOCK_BYTES));
            infoheap.erase(infoheap.begin() + x);
            return;
        }
    }
}

void* BSmartheap::allocate_block(size_t sizeBytes)
{
    if (sizeBytes == 0)
    {
        throw exception("Size is null");
    }
    void* newPtr = malloc(sizeBytes + SIZEBLOCK_BYTES);
    if (newPtr == nullptr)
    {
        throw exception("malloc return nullptr");
    }
    reinterpret_cast<size_t*>(newPtr)[0] = sizeBytes;
    newPtr = move_pointer_right<void>(newPtr, SIZEBLOCK_BYTES);
    infoheap.push_back(newPtr);
    return &infoheap[infoheap.size() - 1];
}

static BSmartheap heap;

int main()
{
    char* ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(heap.allocate_block(6));
    const char* str = "Hello";
    for (size_t x = 0; x < 6; x++)
    {
        ptr[x] = str[x];
    }

    cout << ptr << endl;
    cout << heap.size_block(ptr) << endl;

    heap.free_memory(ptr);
    system("pause");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Текст ошибки надо приводить в вопросе, а код должен быть минимальным необходимым для воспроизведения ошибки.

Comment: Но ведь код воспроизводит ошибку.. Разве нет? У меня исключение в отладчике на 46 строчке. Visual studio 2019, x64. @Kromster

Comment: Здорово что ошибка воспроизводится, но все же ruSO это не индивидуальная консультация, где другие участники будут брать весь ваш код, запускать у себя и искать в нем ошибки. Код должен быть минимальным, а ошибка явно процитирована. 80% подобных проблем решается уже на этапе составлении минимального примера, а из остальных, 80% решается глазами, без запуска IDE. Не усложняйте жизнь тем, к кому обращаетесь за помощью )

Comment: Но как мне сделать его минимальным? Я должен его обрезать как-то что-ли? Или вы хотите чтобы я добавил описание исключения "Нарушение доступа для чтения"? Я просто решил отредактировать свой старый вопрос, мне уже не нужен ответ. @Kromster

Comment: Да, следует обрезать и удалять все лишнее, что не вызывает ошибки. Заодно попрактикуетесь в отладке. А текст ошибки следует дословно приводить в самом вопросе.

Comment: Я оставил лишь те методы, которые нужны чтобы получить ошибку. (И ещё 1 метод который нужен чтобы удалить блок памяти. Не хочется комментариев по типу "А как удалять будешь?") Указал текст ошибки. @Kromster

Comment: В таком случае странно, что у меня выделяется под long long 8 байт, а не 4. А так у меня просто uint64 == long long. На x32 long long == 4 байта, верно ведь? @StanislavVolodarskiy

Comment: `uint64` не `long long`. `uint64` - `uint64_t` - тип который везде и всюду занимает восемь байт.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<uint64*>(newPtr)[0] = sizeBytes;` - неопределённое поведение.

Comment: Хорошо, буду знать. Заменил все uint64 на size_t. Но почему ```reinterpret_cast<size_t*>(newPtr)[0] = sizeBytes;``` - неопределённое поведение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А зачем вы возвращаете не полученный адрес, а адрес элемента, его содержащего?

```
return infoheap[infoheap.size() - 1];
```

вместо

```
return &infoheap[infoheap.size() - 1];
```

вас спасет — но только от крэша при освобождении в памяти, потому что у вас таких обращений в коде полно... Пересмотрите их самостоятельно!

Comment: Попробуйте все же еще раз пройтись отладчиком и понять, что указатель, который вы возвращаете и в который пишете — это совсем не тот, который был выделен. Тот адрес вы в результате записи затираете, что и является причиной неприятностей при освобождении памяти — по невалидному указателю. Просто посмотрите и запишите все адреса...

Comment: Посмотрите https://ideone.com/f1cqUo - видите: `_Ptr` сдвигается на 8 байт, но **возвращаете** вы совершенно иное значение, и пишете потом, мягко говоря, мимо выделенной памяти.